# How to make the detail band, matches the content of the textfield containing?

Tags: jasper-reports, stretch

I have a detail band in my jasper report, but this band does not fit the contents of the field to which you sent the most text, then this container detail band and fields he owns.

I have placed all the fields in the detail band the following properties:

- Position Type = Float
- Stretch Type = Relative to Tallest Object
- Stretch With Overflow = check

For band detail I have placed the following property:

- Split Type = Stretch

I may be doing wrong, or should I place additional?

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="10">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="42" y="0" width="57" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{codigo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="99" y="0" width="142" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descripcion}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="241" y="0" width="42" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lote}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="283" y="0" width="29" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="312" y="0" width="57" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cantidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="369" y="0" width="85" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{precioUnitario}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="454" y="0" width="99" height="10" uuid="fe546361-32de-4ac2-861d-b84f704a429c"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
                <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{valorTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```